# How to add Minio S3 to a existing RESTful web services in Dropwizard?

Tags: rest, dropwizard, minio

I want to add a minio object storage to my existing Dropwizard project.

At the moment I run the Dropwizard with RESTful services. I would like to an object storage Minio S3 to it. My idea was to have a website - maybe with webserver in the future - so that I can point to file and upload it to the minio server. I would like to run it through Dropwizard so that the front end only needs to connect to Dropwizard.

How could this be achieved? How is the file transferred from the local filesystem to the minio server and how would I connected my dropziward to minio.